# Notation for discrete cross-correlation

Tags: notation

Consider two real valued vectors $x$ and $y$.  Suppose $x$ is $m$ dimensional and $y$ is $n$ dimensional with $n \ge m$.  What is good notation for the function which returns an $n-m+1$-dimensional vector whose $i$th element is 
$$f(x,y)[i] = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} x[j] y[i+j]  \;?$$

Should it be

$$f(x,y) = x \star y \;?$$

Comment: Are you simply asking for people's opinion? If so, this is not a good question for this site. Check the [Help Center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @robjohn I would like to know what is the standard mathematical notation, if there is one.  Anything with references to sources would of course be even better.

Comment: Are you thinking of convolution? This is not convolution.

Comment: @robjohn It's essentially the same as convolution if you reverse $x$ I think.

Comment: In the formula above, you can pull the $x[i]$ out front since it is independent of the summation. Convolution would be $$x\ast y[i]=\sum_{j=0}^ix[j]y[i-j]$$

Comment: @robjohn Oh sorry that was a silly typo by me. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As long as you define what you mean by each symbol, it really doesn't matter what symbols you use. Using commonly used symbols reduces confusion. Is '$\star$' used in this way elsewhere? Is any other symbol?

Comment: @robjohn This is my problem. I don't know the math literature well enough to find examples where discrete cross-correlation has been discussed before.  My guess was from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-Correlation.html but that is not the discrete case.